# Cancel Handler for workflow not execute (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I'm developing workflows on SharePoint 2010 using Visual Studio.

I need to catch event, when user cancel running workflow from UI.
User clicks on "Terminate this workflow now" link and I should add some logs to history of current workflow instance.

I added **cancellationHandlerActivity** for my SequentialWorkflowActivity, but cancellationHandlerActivity is not executed.

[image]

In MSDN I find explanation for cancellationHandlerActivity (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa349442(v=vs.85).aspx) - *The CancellationHandlerActivity activity contains **cleanup logic for a composite activity that is canceled** before all the composite activity's child activities are finished executing.*

So I thought, that cancellationHandlerActivity is what I need, but on practice - I'm wrong :(

Please, give me some advice, how i can solve my problem!
I tried to find solution on the Internet, but couldn't :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution!

You can create your custom **WrkStatPage** and add your custom action on cancel event.
([More information about this way](http://leonidius2010.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/sharepoint-intercepting-workflow-cancellation-event/))

Also in **Element.xml** for your workflow add property

```
StatusUrl="_layouts/MyCustomWrkStat.aspx"
```

Comment: cancellationHandlerActivity is still not working for you? I am stuck on this too...

Comment: As I found out, cancellationHandlerActivity shouldn't be used in this case. CancellationHandlerActivity will execute if a Parent activity calls it.  The best example of this is a ParallelActivity when one branch throws an exception while the other one was executing.